# System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException on MongoDb.Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

all.
I created Rest API with ASP.NET 4 and Mongo. It works fine in my local PC under Windows 10, also it works fine in test environment under Windows 2008 R2 + .NET 4.7.1. But it doesn't work on my prod environment under Windows 2012 R2 + .NET 4.7.1, I got the following error:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Multiple custom attributes of the same type found.
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.get_FrameworkDescription()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.CreateClientDocument(String applicationName)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnectionFactory..ctor(ConnectionSettings settings, IStreamFactory streamFactory, IEventSubscriber eventSubscriber)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Configuration.ClusterBuilder.BuildCluster()
   at MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.CreateCluster(ClusterKey clusterKey)
   at MongoDB.Driver.ClusterRegistry.GetOrCreateCluster(ClusterKey clusterKey)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(MongoClientSettings settings)
   at Treolan.Catalog.Providers.BaseDataProvider..ctor(IAppSettings appSettings) in D:\Projects\TreolanCatalog\Treolan\Treolan.Catalog.Providers\BaseDataProvider.cs:line 39
   at Treolan.Catalog.Providers.Categories.CategoriesProvider..ctor(IAppSettings appSettings) in D:\Projects\TreolanCatalog\Treolan\Treolan.Catalog.Providers\Categories\CategoriesProvider.cs:line 22
   at Treolan.Catalog.WebApi.Controllers.CategoriesController.<>c.<.ctor>b__6_0() in D:\Projects\TreolanCatalog\Treolan\Treolan.Catalog.WebApi2\Controllers\CategoriesController.cs:line 31
   at Treolan.Catalog.WebApi.Controllers.CategoriesController.<Get>d__7.MoveNext() in D:\Projects\TreolanCatalog\Treolan\Treolan.Catalog.WebApi2\Controllers\CategoriesController.cs:line 48
```

I found the similar issue, but other developers used Application Insight on Azure. I don't use Application Insight or Azure.

I tried to use MongoDb.Driver 2.5.0 and 2.6.1 but I got the same issue.

Could you help me?

Comment: Are you actually using CosmosDB in production as opposed to MongoDB locally? If so then that would explain a lot. MongoDB and CosmosDB are simply not the same thing. No amount of compatibility claims can change that fact. If not, then trace it down to the particular piece of code which raises the exception

Comment: No. I use only MongoDb on all environments.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and after searching I have found a solution for me

My app is in an Azure VM

To solve this

Go to this machine using Terminal Server, 
go to Control Panel,
go to programs/features
remove the application insights status monitor toolkit from server

This have resolved the issue for me

Hope it helps

Comment: @AlexanderPoplooukhin nice!